# Is opening both TCP/UDP less secured than just TCP or UDP when needed and why?

Tags: firewalls, ports

If application needs opened port X UDP, or X TCP combination. Is there any potential risk by opening both UDP/TCP as I usually am not sure which one the application uses?

Comment: "_I usually am not sure which one the application uses?_" **Then ask for help.** Ask others "which protocols/ports do _xxxx_ uses?" or rather, ask "how do I determine which protocols/ports _xxxx_ uses?" **You cannot properly configure a firewall if you have no idea which network protocols are used.**

Comment: You are right, but that is why I'm asking, is worth knowing, does it make any difference. If it does I'll look into it.

Comment: I am actually saying that _a firewall hurts more than it helps_ when used by less-than-experts (it can cause a lot of confusion, and does not protect much, if at all). I know that this is **not** exactly the consensus in the security community. So I am actually suggesting to _not enable the firewall_ in the first place.

Comment: @curiousguy Windows Vista/7's firewall has actually come a long way in preventing the confusion you're talking about (unlike most/all third party firewalls, which block ^%&%ing everything), so I think think it's very true anymore that only someone with a Computer Science degree should have an active firewall.

Comment: These days everyone should be running a firewall. Windows firewall is now very good out of the box, for a home user. @Gowenfawr's answer is good.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, SSH needs port 22/tcp.  You're asking if opening 22/tcp and 22/udp presents a security vulnerability.  The answer is "no" if nothing is listening to 22/udp. If some other application is listening to 22/udp, an application which you wouldn't want open to other hosts, then it could.  There are such combinations (syslog and rsh share 514, for example).

That being said, there's really not much excuse for not knowing which an application uses.  On Linux, for example, you can use `netstat -tunlp` or `lsof -i` to see which program is listening to which port(s), and tune your firewall rules correctly.

Comment: You don't have to have the software running to find its port. The very most ports are listed in /etc/services.

Comment: /etc/services lists expectations but not necessarily realities, especially for anything that isn't standard, low,  and reasonably old.  For example, squid is going to open several ports (56624/udp? huhwhat?) that services doesn't know anything about, and services thinks that squids actual proxy port (3128/tcp) is ndl-aas (the Active API Server Port, of course!)

Answer (score 2):

Just want to expand on @gowenfawer 's really outstanding answer.

Even if a process is not ***currently*** listening on a specified port, that might not be true in the ***future***...

IE: Somebody is hosting a SMTP server; it shifts mail around. There's no webserver  on it, so the admin leaves ports ***tcp/80*** & ***TCP/443*** wide open.  Neither Apache or Nginx are running on it, so why bother writing an ***iptables*** rule?

Then someone hacks his ***mailserver*** and starts running a ***webserver*** hosting illegal content: could be porn, malware, who knows; the mind boggles at what the miscreant could serve from somebody else's server.  Indeed, a smart skunk doesn't stink-up their own hole: people who do that sort of thing are going to use other folk's servers.

Had those ports been preemptively filtered, disaster would have been averted.  ***Remember: you're only paranoid when they're not really out to get you***